# What is the basic step to create a wizard with sql db in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am just curious about wizardstep in asp.net. I am trying to create wizard step in asp.net for register the company and workers from their company and I have created the wizardstep and tried to put all data input into the sql server.

However there are many workers in the company so what I have tried is to create an arraylist and put info into the array when user click add person button and when click finish button, insert all data using for loop including company info into the sql.

I have searched some of the articles and most of them are trying to insert in aspx page but what I have tried was insert from code behind.

Also I have sql data with foreign key relates to the company db and company has to be created first if I want to insert the each worker so I guess I had to put all data into the arraylist to save each worker and insert them all together when finish clicks.

If there is any best example somewhere, it would be much appreciated but please give me any idea if there is any easy way to put it in.

Thanks

Comment: I can't tell from your question where your problem lies.  Do you need information about using the Wizard control, or about adding records to your database?  If the answer is "both", I would ignore the wizard control for now and focus on learning about using the database.

Comment: Hi Ann Thanks for your comment. My main question is what is the best way to input my data using wizard steps. As I mentioned above, I have created wizard step and sql data but I am not sure if I am doing right way. I am just wondering what is most effiecient way to put it into sql and want to see how the other people do. So if there is any example, that would be great. Thanks